# Setting up RSpec in VSCode (not rails) on a Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code, rspec

In my `launch.json` file I have this simple configuration:

```json
{
    "name": "Run RSpec - all",
    "type": "Ruby",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "/Users/timregan/.asdf/shims/rspec",
},
```

(N.B. `/Users/timregan/.asdf/shims/rspec` is wthe result from running  `which rspec` at the zsh terminal.)

When I run this I get the error

```
Uncaught exception: /Users/timregan/.asdf/shims/rspec:3: unknown regexp options - hbrw. 
exec /opt/homebrew/opt/asdf/libexec/bin/asdf ex...  
         ^~~~~~~~~  
/Users/timregan/.asdf/shims/rspec:3: syntax error, unexpected local variable or method, expecting `do' or '{' or '(' 
.../opt/asdf/libexec/bin/asdf exec "rspec" "$@"  
...                           ^~~~

    /Users/timregan/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.1/bin/rdebug-ide:23:in `load'
    /Users/timregan/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.1/bin/rdebug-ide:23:in `<main>'
```

Running `rspec` at the terminal outside VSCode runs the test as expected without error.

Note that adding `"cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",` to the configuration does not affect the error.

I have various Ruby VSCode extensions installed:

- [Ruby](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.Ruby)
- [VSCode Ruby](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wingrunr21.vscode-ruby)
- [ruby-robocop](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=misogi.ruby-rubocop)
- [Rails Test Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=davidpallinder.rails-test-runner)

My configuration is a cut-down version of the one in [this VSCode recipe](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/debugging-Ruby-on-Rails). Left unchanged (e.g. with the arguments added to the configuration) that recipe gives me the same error.

What's going on and how might I fix it?

Comment: This is more of a workaround than an explanation of what's going wrong, but [Connor Shea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7143763/connor-shea)'s VSCode extension [Ruby Test Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=connorshea.vscode-ruby-test-adapter) enabled me to run and debug RSpec tests of my Ruby code from VSCode

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the result of `which rspec`, use the result of `asdf which rspec`:

```bash
/Users/Foo/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.1/bin/rspec
```